# Singleton pattern with current Thread type authority

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton, access-control

I'm not interested in instantiating `POJO`s by passing parameters through constructors. Also my design is such that I only need one instance of every type. Instantiating more `Object`s from each type is not desired.
So let's consider I have a class `Launcher.java`. I use singleton pattern and get one instance through `static getInstance()` method. `Launcher.java` needs a component named `Transceiver.java`. I also instantiate this class through singleton pattern.
Now I want to, **for example**, pass some parameters to my `Transceiver` only and only through `Launcher` instance.
What I do is like:

```
public void setParameter (int parameter) throws IllegalTypeAccessException
{
    if (Strand.getCurrentStrand() instanceof Launcher)
    // or if (Thread.getcurrentThread() instanceof Launcher)
    {
        this.parameter = paramater;
    }
    else
    {
        IllegalTypeAccessException e = new IllegalTypeAccessException(Strand.getCurrentStrand().getClass().getTypeName()
                                   + " Is not authorized to set property for this object");
        throw e;
    }
}
```

By doing so, unauthorized accesses are controlled. Only one Java type can set them and because I'm using singleton pattern for every type I use, then only one object can do that. Accesses are controlled in terms of both `Type` and `Instance`.
Also there is no need to boring and prone to mistake parameter passing through constructors.
Now I want to ask, are there any flaws that I should consider in this type of design? Will I face problems using this pattern?
Please feel free to edit my question if you think it may be improved to have professional answers.

Comment: If `Transceiver` is to be accessed exclusively from `Launcher` consider making it a private inner class.

Comment: @PM77-1 I'm not going to do that because if I want to integrate all the classes in one type my code will be so messy.

Comment: it seems that you're overengineering